# Is there possible to remove 1 records or max(id) from GROUP_CONCAT MYSQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, count, group-concat, having

[image]I have to remove/skip the 1st records or max id in group_concat MYSQL.
Here is query

```
select email, group_concat(id order by id desc) as id 
from api_admin.external_user 
group by email 
having count(1) > 1;
```

Comment: Please show sample input and expected outcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `GROUP_CONCAT()` returns a string which is a comma separated list of at least 2 ids (because of the condition in the `HAVING` clause) sorted descending.
You can use the function [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to get the part of the returned string after the first comma:

```
SELECT email, 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY id DESC), ',', -COUNT(*) + 1) AS ids 
FROM external_user 
GROUP BY email 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6599aa8f61d0f0c0e0e526b34bee9cf0).

Answer (score 0):

Looks as sub-query approach:

```
select email, group_concat(id order by id desc) as id 
from external_user 
where id not in (
  -- here filter out records with max id per email
  select max(id) as max_id from external_user group by email 
)
group by email;
```

[SQL online environment](https://sqlize.online/sql/mariadb/59aab9bdd65dcb220825f716db565c69/)

Comment: thanks, that would work but this will increase the complexity as you add sub Query.